# Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am following an android development course of Udacity [Intents and activity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud839/lessons/7633778648/concepts/2eef07a4-abb3-448f-8025-8aeb7cf21621)

here they are asking for importing a project from GitHub [GitHub project repository link.](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code)
while importing the project and developing the app I got an error

Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V'
com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)V

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

[image: gradle error image]

here is gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

here is build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
}

dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

please let me know how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572654/gradle-project-sync-failed-in-android-studio-while-developing-app/48416232